# Select of Type State in Contact form 7

Tags: contact-form-7

Am using Contact form 7 and need your help with the following use case:

- Select a country from a drop-down list.
- Select a country from a drop-down list.
- Select state from drop-down list if a specific country’s states are known.
- Type in the state if specific country’s states are unknown.
- State information is stored in same field, whether selected from drop-down list, or typed in.

Example data:

- Country= “C1” “C2” “C3” “C4” “C5”
- C1-states= “a” “b” “c” “d”
- C2-states= “w” “x” “y” “z”

Expected behavior:

- User will select Country from drop-down list.
- User will select their appropriate State from drop-down list for C1 and C2
- User will type in their State for C3, C4, C5.

Tried using the plugin 'Conditional Fields for Contact Form 7' but it does not seem to work.

Here is the Contact form 7 form I used with conditional field plugin:

```
<label> Country (required)</label>
[text Country]
[select* Country “C1” “C2” “C3” “C4” “C5”]

[group C1]
<label> State (required)</label>
[select* C1-states “a” “b” “c” “d”]
[/group]

[group C2]
<label> State (required)</label>
[select* C2-states “w” “x” “y” “z”]
[/group]

[group states-1][group states-2]
[/group][/group]
```

And used the following conditions:

```
if [Country] equals "C1" then show [C1-states]
if [Country] equals "C2" then show [C2-states]
if [Country] not equals "C1" then show [state-1]
if [Country] not equals "C2" then show [state-2]
```

In the webpage display, I see two input boxes for the Country with no drop-down box or the state box. Can you help with above? Alternately, is there perhaps some JavaScript I can input in the Contact form 7 function, which may work here? Thanks in advance for your help.